# how do I vs. how do you

Tags: american-english, subjects

I was wondering which one is used more often by Americans when asking something?

How do you get the the train station?

vs

How do I get to the train station?

I think British use 'one', which I think is more clear.

but Is there a difference between them when Americans say it?

In that case, I think you can say both. Which one sounds more natural?

but how about a case just for myself?
For example, I need to tell my dad something sensitive and hard to bring up and I ask someone for advice on how I should talk to him.

Would you say, "how do I tell my dad..." or "how would you tell your dad..."

The use of 'I' and 'you' is really confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Americans don't ask, "How do you get to the train station?"  Americans don't take very many trains.  Many Americans have never been on one.

> Correct: How do you get the the train station?
>
> Correct: How do I get to the train station?

Americans say it both ways to ask for directions to the train station.  Whether you say "you" or "I," it means the same thing.

You may say, "How does one get to the train station," but it would sound rather stilted, even in the UK.  Most people in the UK would say, "How do I get to Waterloo Station?" or, "What way to the train depot?" (I only know this from watching extensive amounts of BBC and hearing the little Brit voice in my head, not from actual experience.)

As for asking your dad:

> Correct: How do I tell my dad...
>
> Correct:  How would I tell my dad...

You would only generally say, "How would you tell your dad..." if you were speaking to someone hypothetically.  You're not asking them how they think you should tell your dad about *it*.  You're asking them how they think they would tell their dad about *it*.

Comment: I would ask,  "How do I get to the train station" when I was intending to immediately follow the directions I received.  I would use "How do you get to the train station" when I was simply interested to know the answer but was not going to follow those directions immediately.

Comment: @Jim : Yes, I pondered on such possible nuances, but then I pictured myself bustling down Lexington Ave. lost and late for my train and stopping some passing stranger and saying, "Hey, buddy, how do you get to Penn Station from here?"